# Accessing HTML page need to hit global.asax

Tags: asp.net, global-asax, static-files

I want static HTML file to hit the global.asax file when it get loaded I am using .NET Framework version 2.0

Comment: It does automatically for asp.net. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It hits the global.asax only if I access aspx pages. It does not hit if I access any other static files